# Read each line entirely regardless of spaces

Tags: bash, shell, makefile

A part of my `makefile` is as follows:

```
list:          all
               for f in \
               `less fetch/list.txt`; \
               do \
                    echo $$f; \
                    ...
               done
```

`fetch/list.txt` contains a list of files:

```
path/file1.ml
path/file2.ml
path/file 3.ml
path/file 4.ml
```

The problem is, even though space is permitted in a file name, `make list` shows:

```
path/file1.ml
path/file2.ml
path/file
3.ml
path/file
4.ml
```

Does anyone know to let each line be read entirely, regardless of spaces?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

```
list:
        while IFS= read -r n ; do echo "line: $$n" ; done < list.txt
```

Here it is in action:

```
$ cat list.txt 
abc
def
123 456

$ gmake
while read n ; do echo "line: $n" ; done < list.txt
line: abc
line: def
line: 123 456
line:
```

Comment: That's a bash gotcha. You definitely want `read -r` in case there are backslashes in the lines, and also you need to be aware that read always strips leading and trailing IFS characters. So you actually need: `while IFS= read -r ...`. Or you can use `mapfile/readarray -t`

Answer (score 1):

```
for files in
$(sed -n '/file/p' list.txt)
do
echo "${files}"
...
done
```

Usually it is true that tying commands to the output of a loop is bad form, but sed can generally do it reliably, because it will always quote the entire line.  You have to make sure you put double quotes (") around the variable name when echoing as well, if you want it output in the same form as the input.

Answer (score 1):

When working with variables that may contain spaces, you must quote them to preserve the spaces. This will work, for example:

```
for f in "$(cat fetch/list.txt)"; do     # preserve spacing from $()
    echo "$f"                            # preserve spacing from $f
done
```

Another couple of suggestions:

- Prefer command substitution `$(...)` to backticks `` `...` `` because it works better with quotes and nesting.
- `less` is an interactive command, use `cat` instead if you just want file content.

But it would be even more efficient to loop over file content directly (as already mentioned in Eric's answer), instead of converting the file to a list of elements to iterate over:

```
while read f; do           # read each line into f
    echo "$f"
done < fetch/list.txt      # from fetch/list.txt
```

Here, `read` reads entire lines (while process substitution and backticks produce lists of items, not necessarily lines, unless you quote it), so you only need quotes when using `$f`.  Note the location of the `<` input redirection: after the `done` keyword, which may look confusing.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you:

```
for file in "$(<list.txt)"; do echo "$file"; done
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution would be to feed `fetch/list.txt` to `xargs` and have that execute your commands for each line in the file:

```
xargs -i sh -c 'echo "${1}" ; ...' _ {} < fetch/list.txt
```

In general `for f in [some list of values that might contain spaces]` should be approached with caution in shell scripts.

Comment: Would the downvoter care to explain why/how this answer was not useful?

Comment: This solution is very inefficient because it starts a new shell for each line of input, and is also harder to read than the alternative (because `xargs` uses non-standard symbols like `_` and `{}`). Finally it is not a no-no to loop over things with spaces, you just have to be aware of how it works and quote it properly.

Comment: @AndersJohansson True. It's messy; I wasn't thinking of a `while read` based solution. You don't need to spawn a new shell for each file, but as the OP didn't show what was in the loop it seemed like the logical choice for a solution template. Not sure efficiency is so big a concern though (would be with a large project on Cygwin where spawning a process is expensive; not so much on Linux with a handful of source files). Made a minor edit - thanks.

Answer (score -1):

This appears to work:

```
list:          all
    for f in "`cat filename`"; \
    do \
        echo "$$f"; \
    done

all:
    /bin/true
```